# java program that writes file to computer on network throws access denied error

Tags: java

Im trying to write a small program that writes to another pc on my network. I send files to this folder regularly but java throws an access denied error to write this txt file. What am I missing?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Answer {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        System.out.println("What ip?");
        String ip = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("message?");
        String message = input.nextLine();
    
        System.out.println("ip is " + ip + "?");
        System.out.println("message is " + message + "?");
    
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("\\\\JOSHY-PC\\Users\\joshy\\Desktop\\New 
folder (4)message.txt");
                    writer.write(ip + message );
                    writer.close();
                
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
What ip?
192.168.1.1
message?
banana
ip is 192.168.1.1?
message is banana?
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\JOSHY-PC\Users\joshy\Desktop\New folder (4)message.txt 
    (Access is denied)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:293)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:123)
        at java.base/java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:67)
        at answerThePhone/answerThePhone.Answer.main(Answer.java:21)
```

Comment: Does the file exist, yet it throws the error?  I've seen this happen when there is still a handle on the file.  Try re-starting the IDE, or restarting the JVM.

Comment: Path looks wrong. Probably `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("\\\\JOSHY-PC\\Users\\joshy\\Desktop\\New 
folder (4)\\message.txt");` btw try forward slashes, halving their number each time.

Comment: You'll do yourself a favour by not creating paths with spaces in them.

Comment: the file does not exist

Comment: double slashes are javas thing not mine and forward slashes are the same pretty much.

Comment: Ill try renaming folder but i pretty much copied it from the file path I use to open that folder

Answer (score -2):

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("\\\\JOSHY-PC\\Users\\joshy\\Desktop\\New  folder (4)\\message.txt");
```

Forgot the last whack whack... how sad

Comment: (As I said) ^^^. That code wouldn't compile though so this is not an answer